# UK visa with minors

Tags: visas, uk

We are applying for a UK visa, along with our 6 year old and 2 year old twins. My husband as the primary got the first available date but  for every application thereafter, we couldn't get times on the same dates unless if we wanted November/December dates.

So after reading online that policy does not allow separation of family, we all went today at my husband's appointment time, only to be told we had to pay £89 per person for me and for each of the children, or we would have to come with them on the 3 different days; even the twins couldn't get thesame day as we wanted dates in October.

Does anyone know what this no separation of minors is about and how I can use it? I don't mind going on my day, but don't understanding having to go to the visa center three different days for the kids.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say the location from where you are making your applications, but you are able to [book a group appointment at a visa application centre](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/lk/en/premium-services/group-appointment-booking). It is a fee-based service and the additional costs quoted to you may be in line with the fees associated either with a group appointment, or with not booking in advance and the centre accommodating a walk-in group.

Those travelling together, including families, may attend group appointments but each person applies and is assessed individually for a visa. A minor may be accompanied by a parent, of course, but it is incorrect to assume that all family/group members may simply appear for an appointment booked for one individual.